# R Chunk option fig.pos not taking effect when generating PDF.

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

I want to apply the fig.pos= 'h' chunk option like so:

````
```{r echo=FALSE , fig.pos='h'}
ggplot() 
```
````

so that when I knit to pdf latex positions my plots (the float) at the precise location in the LaTeX code. It is my understanding that this should make my latex code look like:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-3-1.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

but instead when I open the generated Tex document I see:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-3-1.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

I am ending up with my plots in random postions in the PDF document instead of where they are located in the latex code, sometimes taking up an entire page for one plot. I have tried fig.pos='h', fig.pos='H',fig.pos='h',fig.pos='h!'and fig.pos='H! based on the table on [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions).

I am attempting this based on [this link](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) where it states under plot chunk options: fig.pos: (''; character) a character string for the figure position arrangement to be used in \begin{figure}[fig.pos]

What am I missing or how else can I ensure my plots are displayed where the text is located within the Rmd file or latex code?